# Prompt : Entered text not showing in terminal

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, terminal

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>iChat - Realtime Node Socket.io Chat App</title>
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="js/client.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <img class="logo" src="chat-removebg-preview (1).png">
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="message right">Jack : Hi Peter </div>
        <div class="message left"> Peter : Hi Jack ! how are you ?</div>

    </div>
    <div class="send">
        <form action="#" id="send-container">
            <input type="text" name="messageInp" id="messageInp">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
const { Socket } = require('socket.io');

// Node server which will handle socket io connections
const io = require('socket.io')(8000)

const users = {};

io.on('connection', Socket => {
socket.on('new-user-joined', Name => {
console.log("New user", Name)
users[socket.id] = Name;
socket.broadcast.emit('user-joined', Name)
    });

socket.on('send', message => {
socket.broadcast.emit('receive', { message: message, Name: users[socket.id] })
    });
})
```

client.js

```
const socket = io('https://localhost:8000');

const form = document.getElementById('send-container');
const messageInput = document.getElementById('messageInp')
const messageContainer = document.querySelector(".container")

const Name = prompt("Enter your name to join")
socket.emit('new-user-joined', Name)
```

I was making a chat website from a tutorial then i typed this this :

```
const Name = prompt ("Enter your name to join") 
socket.emit ('new-user-joined', Name)
```

I was expecting that I would type the name of anything in the prompt area on website and it will show in terminal but it showed nothing in terminal when i typed and i refreshed many times and used nodemon also to make sure my code was updated

Answer (score 0):

You need an http server. I did not see that you created an http server in your codes. Please check the official documentation.

You can try this ;

index.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(8000);

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

const socketio = require("socket.io");
const io = socketio(server);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("new-user-joined", data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

client.js

```js
const socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
const name = prompt("Enter your name to join");
socket.emit('new-user-joined', name);
```

This code will work without any problems.